# how to filter nested list in python

Tags: python

I have the follow list:

```
my_list = [
 [0, 0, [21, 24]],
 [0, 1, [2, 13]],
 [0, 3, [1, 15]],
 [0, 4, [1, 6]],
 [0, 6, [11]],
 [0, 7, [1]],
 [1, 0, [3, 4, 10, 17]],
 [1, 1, [1, 15, 19, 24]],
 [1, 2, [1]],
 [1, 3, [5, 6, 18]],
 [1, 4, [15, 24, 25]],
 [1, 5, [10, 22]],
 [1, 6, [16, 30, 31]],
 [2, 0, [7, 20]],
 [2, 1, [5]],
 [2, 3, [11, 14]],
 [2, 4, [5, 10]],
 [2, 5, [15]],
 [2, 6, [6, 10]],
 [2, 7, [12]],
 [3, 0, [11, 18]],
 [3, 2, [2, 22]],
 [3, 5, [8]],
 [3, 6, [15]],
 [3, 7, [5]]
]
```

I want to retrieve the follow data:

[x,y,[z]][x+1,y+1,[z]][x+2,y+2,[z]][x+3,y+3,[z]]

should get:

```
[0, 3, [1, 15]],     
[1, 4, [15, 24, 25]],
[2, 5, [15]],      
[3, 6, [15]],
```

where x is a index of character in a word, y is line number and z is column number.
z as you can see can be more than 1 option

```
final = [(i,j,) for i,j in my_list if i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1]+1 and i[2]==j[2]]
```

getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: What's your expected output? There are other issues with your code as well (getting `int` object is unsubscriptable now).

Comment: what is `character` - all your values are integers? And what element do you want to get/receive?

Comment: edit the question the final result should be:[0, 3, 15],     
[1, 4, 15,],
[2, 5, 15],      
[3, 6,  15],

Answer (score 2):

Each element of `my_list` has three elements which you are trying to unpack into 2. That's too many.

```
>>> i, j = [0, 0]
>>> i, j = [0, 0, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> i, j = [0, 0, [21, 24]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> i, j, k = [0, 0, [21, 24]]
>>> i
0
>>> j
0
>>> k
[21, 24]
```